# Excel group by distinct values and keep detail

Tags: excel

I have following table:

| CODE |
| --- |
| A10 |
| A20 |
| A20 |
| B10 |
| B10 |
| B20 |
| C30 |

---

And want to achieve something like that:

| Letter | Codes starting with that letter |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A10 | A20 |
| B | B10 | B20 |
| C | C30 |  |

---

In general:
I want to get the **letter of the Code once** and display **all codes starting with it next to it**.

I'm would be very happy if sb knows a solution **without macros/scripts**.

---

Edit:
My Excel Version is: `Microsoft Excel 2016 (16.0.5188.1000)`

Comment: Which excel version you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A2:$A1000)/((LEFT($A2:$A1000,1)=$D2)*((COUNTIF($D2:D2,$A2:$A1000))=0)),1)),"")
```

[image]